# How to select child element based on parent element using java script query selector

Tags: javascript, html

my page multiple element have same class like below

```
<div>
 <ol class="sample-class">
  <li>list1</li>
  <li>list2</li>
  <li>list3</li>
 </ol>
 <div class="help">condent 1</div>
</div>
....
</div>
 <ol class="sample-class">
   <li>list1</li>
   <li>list2</li>
   <li>list3</li>
  </ol>
 <div class="help">condent 2</div>
</div
```

I need to change the help content based on **sample-class**
I js to select the element but it is not working.

```
let listVal = document.getElementsByClassName('sample-class');
for(let el of listVal) {
 el.offsetParent.getElementsByClassName('help')[0].innerHTML = "my dynamic condent"
}
```

anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: Wait, The ID should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new querySelector in the for loop to select the element with the `help` class/id, you can achieve this by doing the following:

**1 By using parentElement**

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".sample-class");
for (const element of elements) {
  element.parentElement.querySelector(".help").innerText = "new text"
}
```

**2 By using sibling selector**

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".sample-class");
for (const element of elements) {
  element.querySelector("~ .help").innerText = "new text"
}
```

Comment: This solution is awesome, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use getElementById to find something inside another element, so you need to use getElementByClassName instead. Also, as mentioned in one of the comments, the ID should be a unique. No 2 elements can have the same ID.

Kindly check the below snippet which would work as expected.

```js
let listVal = document.getElementsByClassName('sample-class');
for(let el of listVal) {
 el.getElementsByClassName('help')[0].innerHTML = "my dynamic condent"
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="sample-class">
        <ol>
            <li>list1</li>
            <li>list2</li>
            <li>list3</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="help">condent 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sample-class">
        <ol>
            <li>list1</li>
            <li>list2</li>
            <li>list3</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="help">condent 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplecated your code by looping over an array and not modifing the array you are looping over. I also like to state that when accessing `getElementById` you always get the first DOM element containing this ID. To fix this issue change the id's to classes and loop over these classes instead of the siblings

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".help");
for (const element of elements) {
  element.innerText = "new text"
}
```

If for some reason you need to loop over the ol elements:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("ol");
for (const element of elements) {
  element.nextSibling.innerText = "new text"
}
```

Comment: I give an example, but the actual scenario may contain other elements also in between.

Answer (score 0):

ID Should be unique on a page and use the nextSibling function.

```
<div>
 <ol class="sample-class">
  <li>list1</li>
  <li>list2</li>
  <li>list3</li>
 </ol>
 <div class="help">condent 1</div>
</div>
....
</div>
 <ol class="sample-class">
   <li>list1</li>
   <li>list2</li>
   <li>list3</li>
  </ol>
 <div class="help">condent 2</div>
</div>
<script>
let listVal = document.getElementsByClassName('sample-class');
for(let el of listVal) {
 el.nextSibling.innerHTML = "my dynamic condent"
}
</scritp>
```

Note: If you add whitespace between the two ol elements, the result will be "undefined".
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but the nextsibling is not working, because maybe some other elements also will come in between.

Comment: Please read the note

Comment: You can use jquery like `$(ths).next().find(".help).text("text here")`